# Generate random RSA keys with RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

How do I generate random RSA public and private keys (RSAParameters) using RSACryptoServiceProvider class?
Each time I create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider, I end up exporting the same keys.

Thanks

Comment: Show your code, don't make us guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some test on the following code, and the exported parameters are always different:

```
var rsaAlgo1 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
var rsaAlgo2 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

var xml1 = rsaAlgo1.ToXmlString(true);
var xml2 = rsaAlgo2.ToXmlString(true);

if (xml1 != xml2)
{
   // it always goes here...
}
```

Comment: This code works, but it is a very dangerous style. The `Create()`-method you are calling is actually a static method on the abstract `RSA`-class (the superclass to `RSACryptoServiceProvider`) and creates an instance of the default implementation of the `RSA`-class. On most systems this will be `RSACryptoServiceProvider` - but not on all. A better style would be either `var rsa = RSA.Create()` or `var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider`.

Comment: Note that for practical use you should specify a key size (e.g. 2048 bits) instead of using the default constructor.

Comment: Randomness in Cryptography can't be checked by a simple comparison. It has to meet  four requirements.  Check them out http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~koc/cren/docs/w06/rng.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code you should never get all the same keys out

```
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
var rsaParams = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
```

However you should note that the **Exponent key** can be the same and if often is **65537(0x010001)**

> "Choose an integer e such that 1 < e < φ(n) and gcd(e, φ(n)) = 1; i.e., e and φ(n) are coprime.
>   e is released as the public key exponent.
>   e having a short bit-length and small Hamming weight results in more efficient encryption – most commonly 216 + 1 = 65,537. However, much smaller values of e (such as 3) have been shown to be less secure in some settings."
>   [RSA wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem))